# Displaying a number from the database in a javascript alert box

Tags: javascript, php, database, data-retrieval

The following code  is to used to display an alert box with the order number when a html form is submitted successfully!

```
$mysql="SELECT MAX(OrderNo.) FROM `order`  ";
 $results=mysqli_query($db,$mysql);

     $row=mysqli_fetch_array($results);

       echo '<script type="text/javascript">';



   echo 'alert("Successful signup your order number is"';
       echo $row['OrderNo.'];
    echo ")";
    echo '</script>';
```

Though the alert box appears with "Successful signup your order number is" part, the OrderNo. part(retrieved from a databse table) does not appear in the alert box! Here max is used because the latest orderNo. is to be displayed and the OrderNo. field is auto incremented.
please help me to correct this error

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing double quotes correctly.

It should be:

```
echo 'alert("Successful signup your order number is ';
echo $row['OrderNo.'];
echo '")';
```

Or better:

```
echo 'alert("Successful signup your order number is '.$row['OrderNo.'].'")';
```

Comment: still the same error exists and after the alert box goes off mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given this error occurs

Comment: Then your `mysqli_query($db,$mysql)` is not executing correctly

Comment: Your problem is currently not in the `alert` part... is on the query part

Comment: `$c=mysqli_connect('servername','username','password','db_name');`.Then pass this variable in every `mysqli_query()` function.  To be used as `mysqli_query($c,"your query");`

Comment: Did you already checked if a mysql error is thrown? 
`echo mysqli_error($db)` after the mysqli_query

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an alias for the grouped number like this:

```
SELECT MAX(OrderNo) AS number FROM order
```

And show with:

```
echo 'alert("Successful signup your order number is' . $row['number'] . '")';
```